# Selenium python with chrome driver, cannot disable image loading

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to disable image loading in chromium with the help of selenium.

### Intro

To disable images, you can follow https://www.webnots.com/how-to-disable-images-in-google-chrome/. It basically edits the `Preference` file, a json, and sets the value `images: 2` in the section `default_content_setting_values`.

### Using Selenium

I could enable this feature via the following code;

```py
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.images": 2})
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://imgur.com")
driver.quit()
```

But unfortunately this does not work.

Other flags used includes;

`"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2`

`"profile.default_content_settings.images": 2`

None of them works.

### Outcome

After launching the browser via the above code, I could see the flag is set in the `Preference` file, but it has no effect, i.e the images still load.
But, If I navigate via the UI to `chrome://settings/content/images` as mentioned in the above url, I can disable the Images manually by toggling the `Show all(recomended)` section.

### Confusion

This feature of disabling image loading via selenium fails. But the confusion lies in the `Preference` files.
My selenium code properly sets the flag in the `Preference` file, yet chrome loads the image.
Now let me keep the Browser initiated via selenium open.
When I manually navigate the UI and disable the feature in this browser, image loading is **prevented!**.
When I reopen the `Preference` file to check if any further updates are made, I find none.
i.e beyond what my selenium script updated in `Preference` file, no changes occurred after my manual toggling via UI.

### Problem

1) I can't disable images via selenium chrome driver.

2) Why does chromium behave this way.

### References:

**Python** = Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)

**Chromium** = Version 80.0.3987.100 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

**Chromedriver** = ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185})

**python selenium** = 3.14.1

**OS** = Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

**Processor** = Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

To find the `Preference` file you can navigate to `chrome://version`